# How to modify the specific value in the html through jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Here is my code:

```
Elements parents = doc.select("input[value]");
for (Element parent : parents) {
    System.out.println(
        parent.attr("value")
            .replace("X70xAkOaaAeWGxNgWnTJolmy6/FFoFaBD47IzyBYWf4=", "Ranjan")
            .replace("17572418", "17572418123")
            .replace("200", "199")
            .replace("2018-09-13T16:28:28Z", "2018-09--5T16:28:28Z")
            .replace("2018-09-17", "2018-09-25")
    );
}
```

But when I print `System.out.println(doc);` it is printing the same old value instead I should get the modified one. How to modify the specific value which are under input tag?

EDIT:

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sessionValidity" value="2018-09-13T16:28:28Z">
<input type="hidden" name="shipBeforeDate" value="2018-09-17"> 
<input type="hidden" name="merchantReturnData" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="shopperLocale" value="en_GB"> 
<input type="hidden" name="skinCode" value="Ce0xkMuQ"> 
<input type="hidden" name="merchantSig" value="X70xAkOaaAeWGxNgWnTJolmy6/FFoFaBD47IzyBYWf4=">
```

Comment: I have the below HTML:
 <input type="hidden" name="sessionValidity" value="2018-09-13T16:28:28Z">
   <input type="hidden" name="shipBeforeDate" value="2018-09-17">
   <input type="hidden" name="merchantReturnData" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="shopperLocale" value="en_GB">
   <input type="hidden" name="skinCode" value="Ce0xkMuQ">
   <input type="hidden" name="merchantSig" value="X70xAkOaaAeWGxNgWnTJolmy6/FFoFaBD47IzyBYWf4=">

Comment: Ranjan, can you edit the post (click on that "edit") and include your HTML fragment there please?

Comment: Did you try to use `doc.html()` instead of `System.out.println(doc)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with Jsoup but it seems like you do not change the value of the attributes. `Element.attr(String s)` returns a String. I guess you meant to use [public Element attr​(String attributeKey, String attributeValue)](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#attr-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Then you use [public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) which does not modify the String itself (String is immutable, `replace` returns a new String)

I think you want to do this way instead:

```
private static String html = 
    "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sessionValidity\" value=\"2018-09-13T16:28:28Z\">\n" +
    "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"shipBeforeDate\" value=\"2018-09-17\"> \n" +
    "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"merchantReturnData\" value=\"\"> \n" +
    "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"shopperLocale\" value=\"en_GB\"> \n" +
    "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"skinCode\" value=\"Ce0xkMuQ\"> \n" +
    "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"merchantSig\" value=\"X70xAkOaaAeWGxNgWnTJolmy6/FFoFaBD47IzyBYWf4=\">";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    doc.select("input[name$=merchantSig]").attr("value", "Ranjan");
    // and the other ones
    System.out.println(doc.html());

}
```

that prints out

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <input type="hidden" name="sessionValidity" value="2018-09-13T16:28:28Z">
        <input type="hidden" name="shipBeforeDate" value="2018-09-17">
        <input type="hidden" name="merchantReturnData" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="shopperLocale" value="en_GB">
        <input type="hidden" name="skinCode" value="Ce0xkMuQ">
        <input type="hidden" name="merchantSig" value="Ranjan">
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see that the `merchantSig` value has been modified

Comment: +1 Yep buddy I solved the issue by using replace method at the places where it was needed to replace the values. But yes your solution works. Cheers